# How to translate POSIXt literals to SQL datetime literals

Tags: r, sql-server, dbplyr, posixlt

I want to use an R `POSIXt` constant in `MS SQL` relying as much as I can on `dbplyr`'s automatic translation. However, it seems to get messed up:

```r
library(dbplyr)
dat <- lubridate::ymd_hms("2022-11-12 00:01:25") 
## class(dat) 
## [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

translate_sql(!!dat, con = simulate_mssql())
## <SQL> '2022-11-12T00:01:25Z'
```

Thus, I need to fall back to a string representation of my date to get the literal in a format MS SQL understands:

```r
translate_sql(!!format(dat, "%F %T"), con = simulate_mssql())
## <SQL> '2022-11-12 00:01:25'
```

Is this the only way to get dates formatted properly? Or is it some obscure locale setting which messes up with the `R` -> `MS SQL` translation in this case?

Comment: `POSIXt` or `POSIXct`? Have you read [Data type mappings between R and SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/r/r-libraries-and-data-types) yet?

Comment: Also, to be `DATFORMAT`-agnostic with string-based dates/times, you would normally insert a `T` between the date and time portions, e.g.: `2022-11-12T00:01:25`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for pointing out that I can use a `T` between date and time, did not know that. So basically, I would need to get rid of the `Z` then? Even specifying the timezone in `GMT` keeps the `UTC` `Z`: `translate_sql(!!lubridate::ymd_hms("2022-11-12 00:01:25", tz = "GMT"), con = simulate_mssql())`

Answer (score 0):

After diving into the code, I identified `dbplyr:::sql_escape_datetime.DBIConnection`  as the culprit which hardcodes a `Z` to the end of the `datetime` literal:

```r
dbplyr:::sql_escape_datetime.DBIConnection
# function (con, x) 
# {
#     x <- strftime(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz = "UTC")
#     sql_escape_string(con, x)
# }
# <bytecode: 0x000001edefa2e680>
# <environment: namespace:dbplyr>
```

I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/1213) as at least for MS-SQL this does not yield [proper datetime literals.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#supported-string-literal-formats-for-datetime)